# How to calculate total of calculated fields on a form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created a form with three fields say working hours,idle time and break time. Each field will have start and end time for its own. I have also created a total column for each field which is a calculated field with the formula be endtime - starttime in the row source till this everything works fine. 
Now I wanted to add a field which should show the sum of the total of all three fields ie total hrs= workinghrs total + idletime total + breaktime total I am not getting results as I am sourcing the calculated fields for further calculation. 
Is there any way to get this done.
I understand questions similar to this are consistently down rated I tried searching several sites but I didn’t find an satisfactory answer hence posting my query. 
Fields are named as follows:

```
   Wkghrs wst wet wtl 
   Idltm  ist iet itl 
   Btm    Bst bet btl 
   Gtl
```

Where wtl,itl,btl refers to the totals of workinghrs, idletime and breaktime respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the definition of your first calculated field as part of the calculation for your second calculated field.

i.e. If your first calculated field is

`workinghours = workingendtime - workingstarttime`

And you want your second calculated field to be:

`total = workinghours + idletime + breaktime`

Then expand your definitions of `workinghours`, `idletime`, & `breaktime` in this second calculation such that no calculated fields are referenced:

```
total = 
    (work_endtime  - work_starttime) + 
    (idle_endtime  - idle_starttime) + 
    (break_endtime - break_starttime)
```

Comment: Thanks you immediate and accurate reply Lee. I tried combining the equations in the total field. I am getting answer if all the three fields have total value. Say if there is no break time the total should be the sum of working hrs. And idle time. That’s doesn’t show up. Could you assist me.

Comment: You may need to account for null values. This is typically handled by the `Nz` function, but since this function cannot be used in a Calculated Field, you would need to include an `iif` statement such as `iif(isnull([wet]-[wst]),0,[wet]-[wst])`

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to find a solution

```
=Nz([wtl],0)+Nz([itl],0)+Nz([btl],0)
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as solving the problem accordingly.